# Is bytecode ("virtual machine code") inherently faster to compile and/or interpret, than higher level (above Assembly) languages?

Tags: compilers, interpreters

First, this is not an opinion question. I'm interested in if there is some kind of objective answer. If there isn't, then the answer would be "no".

Is bytecode ("virtual machine code" for a "virtual processor") inherently faster to compile and/or interpret, than higher level (above Assembly) languages? What I mean is, does the bytecode map to the machine instructions of the underlying processor more easily than some higher level language? Why I ask is, it doesn't seem entirely certain to me that it does.

Answer (score 4):

> does the bytecode map to the machine instructions of the underlying processor more easily than some higher level language?

That depends entirely on the bytecode, the higher level language, and the machine instructions.

For example, [*Haskell*](https://haskell.org/) semantics map closely to the [*Reduceron* CPU](https://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/reduceron/), whereas [*JVM bytecode*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/) semantics do not.

[*ESPOL*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Systems_Problem_Oriented_Language) semantics map closely to the [*B5000*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Burroughs_Large_Systems), whereas [*CLI CIL*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) semantics do not.

[*C*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) semantics map better to [*AMD64*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) than *JVM bytecode* does, but *JVM bytecode* semantics map better to [*picoJava*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/PicoJava) than C does – in fact, JVM bytecode *is* picoJava's machine code.

For every pair of high level language and bytecode, one can design a CPU that performs horrible for one or the other.